# Leibinitz's Rule

Tags: calculus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule I am really struggling with how to think about integrating a function with limits being two other functions. What does this mean?

Comment: It means exactly the same thing as it would if it were numbers as the limits instead, just that those numbers vary depending on the value of $x$.  Notice that the integral is with respect to $t$, not with respect to $x$.  You know how to integrate $\int\limits_a^b f(t)dt$, then you also know how to integrate $\int\limits_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t,x)dt$

Comment: What i am really having a tough time to do is think about this like  a Riemann sum. Can i even think about this like a Riemann sum if the limits are x and sin x?

Answer (score 0):

Take $y>1$.

Can you caulculate $F(y)=\int _y ^{2y} 2x.dx$?

Both upper and lower limits are functions of $y$. Those would take different values as you vary $y$ in $[1,\infty)$. Now Leibniz rule says what happens if we differentiate the integral w.r.t $y$.

Evaluate $F$, and differentiate it w.r.t $y$, and then do the same using L-rule, compare the results. This should help you understand the rule.

Comment: For a simple function like y i still get it but what happens when the two limits are lets say x and sin x. Can I think about this just like a Riemann sum if so how?

Comment: The limits generally should not be the same variable as the one used for integration. That would make things confusing. But otherwise, why not!

Comment: Can you give me a geometric view if possible with one example maybe?